# How to remove strings which do not start or end with specific substring?

Tags: regex, perl

Unfortunately, I'm not a regex expert, so I need a little help.

I'm looking for the solution how to grep an array of strings to get two lists of strings which do not start (1) or end (2) with the specific substring.

Let's assume we have an array with strings matching to the following rule:

> [speakerId]-[phrase]-[id].txt

i.e.

> 10-phraseone-10.txt 11-phraseone-3.txt 1-phraseone-2.txt
>   2-phraseone-1.txt 3-phraseone-1.txt 4-phraseone-1.txt
>   5-phraseone-3.txt 6-phraseone-2.txt 7-phraseone-2.txt
>   8-phraseone-10.txt 9-phraseone-2.txt 10-phrasetwo-1.txt
>   11-phrasetwo-1.txt 1-phrasetwo-1.txt 2-phrasetwo-1.txt
>   3-phrasetwo-1.txt 4-phrasetwo-1.txt 5-phrasetwo-1.txt
>   6-phrasetwo-3.txt 7-phrasetwo-10.txt 8-phrasetwo-1.txt
>   9-phrasetwo-1.txt 10-phrasethree-10.txt 11-phrasethree-3.txt
>   1-phrasethree-1.txt 2-phrasethree-11.txt 3-phrasethree-1.txt
>   4-phrasethree-3.txt 5-phrasethree-1.txt 6-phrasethree-3.txt
>   7-phrasethree-1.txt 8-phrasethree-1.txt 9-phrasethree-1.txt

Let's introduce variables:

- `$speakerId`
- `$phrase`
- `$id1`, `$id2`

I would like to grep a list and obtain an array:

1. with elements which contain specific `$phrase` but we exclude those strigns which simultaneously start with specific `$speakerId` AND end with one of specified id's (for instance `$id1` or `$id2`)
2. with elements which have specific `$speakerId` and `$phrase` but do NOT contain one of specific ids at the end (warning: remember to not exclude the 10 or 11 for `$id=1` , etc.)

Maybe someone coulde use the following code to write the solution:

```
@AllEntries = readdir(INPUTDIR);

@Result1 = grep(/blablablahere/, @AllEntries);

@Result2 = grep(/anotherblablabla/, @AllEntries);

closedir(INPUTDIR);
```

Comment: I believe you're looking for negative look-ahead (`(?!...)`) and look-behind (`(?<!...)`) assertions (to exclude specific components in a match).

Comment: It would be helpful to know how your ruleset (contain a specific phrase, start with a specific ID, end with one of some IDs) is defined. Are these rules fixed or do you need to read them from a file for example?

Comment: Guys, thanks for replies! I tried to use negative look-ahead, but with no success. I forgot how to use regexps, so any examples whould be useful. :) To specify the usecase: I'd like to run the test app on only some of txt files. For example, on files that have phraseone and are spoken by the first speaker, but do not have id 1,2 or 3. (id's can be [1..100])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like the approach with pure regular expressions using negative lookaheads and -behinds. However, it's a little bit hard to read. Maybe code like this could be more self-explanatory. It uses standard perl idioms that are readable like english in some cases:

```
my @all_entries      = readdir(...);
my @matching_entries = ();

foreach my $entry (@all_entries) {

    # split file name
    next unless /^(\d+)-(.*?)-(\d+).txt$/;
    my ($sid, $phrase, $id) = ($1, $2, $3);

    # filter
    next unless $sid eq "foo";
    next unless $id == 42 or $phrase eq "bar";
    # more readable filter rules

    # match
    push @matching_entries, $entry;
}

# do something with @matching_entries
```

If you really want to express something that complex in a `grep` list transformation, you could write code like this:

```
my @matching_entries = grep {

    /^(\d)-(.*?)-(\d+).txt$/
    and $1 eq "foo"
    and ($3 == 42 or $phrase eq "bar")
    # and so on

} readdir(...)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I took a little bit of your 1st solution and adapted it to my needs.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a basic pattern to match your example:

```
(?:^|\b)(\d+)-(\w+)-(?!1|2)(\d+)\.txt(?:\b|$)
```

Which breaks down as:

```
(?:^|\b)    # starts with a new line or a word delimeter
(\d+)-      # speakerid and a hyphen
(\w+)-      # phrase and a hyphen
(\d+)       # id
\.txt       # file extension
(?:\b|$)    # end of line or word delimeter
```

You can assert exclusions using negative look-ahead. For instance, to include all matches that do not have the phrase `phrasetwo` you can modify the above expression to use a negative look-ahead:

```
(?:^|\b)(\d+)-(?!phrasetwo)(\w+)-(\d+)\.txt(?:\b|$)
```

Note how I include `(?!phrasetwo)`. Alternatively, you find all `phrasethree` entries that end in an even number by using a look-behind instead of a look-ahead:

```
(?:^|\b)(\d+)-phrasethree-(\d+)(?<![13579])\.txt(?:\b|$)
```

`(?<![13579])` just makes sure the last number of the ID falls on an even number.

Comment: And for reference and testing you can use [this site](http://regexr.com?32rtg) to try out your pattern before implementing it.

Comment: Cool! First of all, I was looking for this website! Second, I now know how those lookahead and other funny little mechanisms work! I've also taken a bit of your solution!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds a bit like you're describing a query function.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -Tw

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my ( $set_a, $set_b ) = query( 2, 'phrasethree', [ 1, 3 ] );

print Dumper( { a => $set_a, b => $set_b } );

# a) fetch elements which
#    1. match $phrase
#    2. exclude $speakerId
#    3. match @ids
# b) fetch elements which
#    1. match $phrase
#    2. match $speakerId
#    3. exclude @ids
sub query {
    my ( $speakerId, $passPhrase, $id_ra ) = @_;

    my %has_id = map { ( $_ => 0 ) } @{$id_ra};

    my ( @a, @b );

    while ( my $filename = glob '*.txt' ) {

        if ( $filename =~ m{\A ( \d+ )-( .+? )-( \d+ ) [.] txt \z}xms ) {

            my ( $_speakerId, $_passPhrase, $_id ) = ( $1, $2, $3 );

            if ( $_passPhrase eq $passPhrase ) {

                if ( $_speakerId ne $speakerId
                    && exists $has_id{$_id} )
                {
                    push @a, $filename;
                }

                if ( $_speakerId eq $speakerId
                    && !exists $has_id{$_id} )
                {
                    push @b, $filename;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return ( \@a, \@b );
}
```